# How to use postcss-scss parser in Nuxt3?

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, postcss, nuxtjs3, postcss-scss

In Nuxt2 i used postcss-scss parser to support inline style comments "//". I used below setup in nuxt.config

```js
export default {
postcss: {
    parser: require('postcss-scss'),
    plugins: {
      'postcss-nested': {},
    }
}
```

How to use postcss-scss parser in Nuxt3? I tired:

```js
import postcssScss from 'postcss-scss'
export default defineNuxtConfig({
postcss: {
    parser: postcssScss,
    plugins: {
        'postcss-nested': {},
    },
  }
})
```

Or maybe there is another way to support postcss inline comments in Nuxt3.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by updating dependencies. Probably newest rc version of Nuxt3 supports it out of the box.

Comment: Give an example of your solution